# How to sort the indices of a pandas multi-index data frame according to a custom order

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

The following is some code to generate a sample dataframe:

```
fruits=pd.DataFrame()
fruits['month']=['jan','feb','feb','march','jan','april','april','june','march','march','june','april']
ind_mnth=fruits['month'].values
fruits['fruit']=['apple','orange','pear','orange','apple','pear','cherry','pear','orange','cherry','apple','cherry']
ind_fruit=fruits['fruit'].values
fruits['price']=[30,20,40,25,30 ,45,60,45,25,55,37,60]
fruits_grp = fruits.set_index([ind_mnth, ind_fruit],drop=False)
```

How to sort the rows of this multi-index dataframe such that the inner index(fruits) under every outer index(month) is sorted according to a custom order, and the rows with the same outer index are grouped together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) series of fruit column with the order as you want, then `set_index` with a `Multiindex.from_arrays` with each level, and `sort_index` like you did

```
# custom order
ord_fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'cherry', 'orange']
# create a ordered Categorical series for the fruits
f = pd.Categorical(fruits['fruit'], categories=ord_fruit, ordered=True)

# get month values, could also be a custom order same idea than above
m = fruits['month'].to_numpy()

# get the result
fruits_grp = fruits.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([m,f])).sort_index()
print(fruits_grp)
              month   fruit  price
april pear    april    pear     45 # pear before cherry
      cherry  april  cherry     60
      cherry  april  cherry     60
feb   pear      feb    pear     40
      orange    feb  orange     20
jan   apple     jan   apple     30
      apple     jan   apple     30
june  apple    june   apple     37
      pear     june    pear     45
march cherry  march  cherry     55 # cherry before orange
      orange  march  orange     25
      orange  march  orange     25
```

Note that `sort_index` will then sort the other levels with alphabetical order, if you don't want that, you can create your own order the same way for each of them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Additionally, can the months be shuffled in a random order, with the remaining conditions intact i.e the inner index(fruits) under every outer index(month) is sorted according to a custom order, and the rows with the same outer index are grouped together. In other words, the outer index(months) should be shuffled in a random order.

Comment: @MedhaChippa one way is to create a categorical series for month but with a random order, here is an idea for m: `m = pd.Categorical(fruits['month'], categories=fruits['month'].sample(frac=1).unique(), ordered=True)`. They are plenty of ways to create the categories to have a random order for the months, but `fruits['month'].sample(frac=1).unique()` is one of them